# htaccess - multiple domain to subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i'm try to do this thing:
I want to redirect all the traffic for a specific domain **A** to a subfolder of the root. I will do the same thing with multiple domains with their subfolder.

Example:

```
www.domaina.it -> /public_html/domainadir/
www.unioncucine.it -> /public_html/unioncucine/
```

For that i have done it using this code that seems to work:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/unioncucine/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?unioncucine\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /unioncucine/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?unioncucine.it$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /unioncucine/index.html [L]
```

It seems to work but not in this case:

I want to access www.unioncucine.it/web in which i have loaded a test joomla page (it has not template because i'm working on it).

If you go here: www.unioncucine.it/web i'm redirected to www.unioncucine.it/unioncucine/web/ and it does not load properly contents.

Going here: www.unioncucine.it/web/ it works fine. (The page is just some words and a css scretch).

```
#Changing
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /unioncucine/$1
#To
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /unioncucine/$1/
```

It seems to work without redirect but all the files inside other folders are not available.

Thank you

Edited:

Changed as you told:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/templates/protostar/ [NC]
RewriteRule ((?:css|js|images)/.+)$ /web/templates/protostar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/unioncucine/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?unioncucine\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /unioncucine/$1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?unioncucine.it$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /unioncucine/index.html [L]
```

But it still don't work: http://www.unioncucine.it/css/template.css

Answer (score 0):

You're getting redirected from `www.domain.it/domainadir/test` to `www.domain.it/domainadir/test/` due to `mod_dir` which adds a trailing slash after a directory.

Add these 2 lines on top of your .htaccess **before other existing code**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

DirectorySlash Off
```

Though you should add rule to add trailing slash as well in your rule as:

```
RewriteEngine On

# fix css/js/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/templates/protostar/ [NC]
RewriteRule ((?:css|js|images)/.+)$ /web/templates/protostar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domainadir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domaina\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainadir/$1/ [L]
```

**For css/js/images** better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

You can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Try `www.domaina.it/test` in a new browser.

Comment: Ok it seems works but going deeply i have this problem: using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainadir/$1/ [L] , the root is loaded but all the other files (like css files) are not loaded due to 404 error. If i put RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainadir/$1 [L] (removing the last '/' and adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f) the files are loaded but i have the previous problem that i'm redirected. I cannot find a  solution that fix both things.

Comment: Also see my update about css/js/images in the answer.

Comment: Sure you can try adding `<base href="/" />` in your page header.

Comment: i have done but it's the same as before. I need to do a .htaccess that fully redirect to a subfolder of the root my website. My objective is to create an FTP access directly on the subfolder and the person does not know anything about this redirecting.

Comment: Ok edit your question and provide real working links for css/js/image files. I will see if rewrite rule is possible.

Comment: Ok i edited my question tell me what you need thank you.

Comment: I still don't see your working links for your css/js/image files. Post the links that load css/js/images files on your website at present.

Comment: You can get them just viewing the html code: example http://www.unioncucine.it/web/templates/protostar/css/template.css now it is working, if I change the htaccess it will not

Comment: ok check update in answer and see `# fix css/js/images` rules that should be your first rule.

Comment: the problem is that it has to work with whatever files i a subdir with whatever extesion. www.unioncucine.it/web/subdir/1.pdf www.unioncucine.it/web/subdir/2.mp3 www.unioncucine.it/web/subdir/3.xls i cannot write all the extension

Comment: There is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line above whih will skip your pdf, mp3 etc files.

Comment: I updated my question with the new code, the css still doesn't work. Use the same link. Thank you

Comment: i will offer you a dinner if you could help me :)

Comment: Without any offer for dinner I have tried my level best to help you and have spent lot of time on your question.

Comment: Ok but why did you put -1 to my question? It's not my fault i tried whatever you told me :(